# Does the windows server version influence the WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-server-2008

I use a listview that contains data, for each line there is information from my database, as well as checkboxes, all in mvvm. 
Everything was working perfectly so far, but now I have a problem. If everything works for all the clients, I have two who have a problem with the screen.

In this case, I have a highlighted line and if I check it, no problem, my checkbox will be check.

[image]

In this case, on the other hand, I can't check the combobox, I literally can't do anything.

[image]

I can check via the "select all", but I can't check any boxes in my listView. There's just "nothing" going on. I see the checkbox but I can't interact with it. I can select the line itself. I can use datepickers, too.

I have the impression that the problem is in the version of windows, because the only one for which it doesn't work is the Windows 2008 R2 server.

I can show my WPF code, but it works for everyone else, including on my pc (Windows 10).

WPF :

```
        <TabControl Grid.Row="2">
        <TabItem Header="Lignes">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding LignesTransfert}"
                      AllowDrop="True"
                      cuil:DragDropExtension.ScrollOnDragDrop="True">
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <EventSetter Event="ListViewItem.DragOver" Handler="ListViewItemDragOver"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="ListViewItem.Drop" Handler="ListViewItemDrop"/>
                        <EventSetter Event="ListViewItem.PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListViewItemPreviewMouseMove"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" >
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Binding Path="BackColor" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="300" 
                                        Header="Libellé">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StLibelle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="300" 
                                        Header="Description">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StDescription}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="80" >
                            <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TousEnJours}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="En Jours" 
                                               Margin="4,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolEnJours}"
                                              Visibility="{Binding EnableEnJours, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Visible}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TousEnHeures}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="En Heures"
                                               Margin="4,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolEnHeures}"
                                              Visibility="{Binding EnableEnHeures, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Visible}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Width="80" >
                            <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TousEnNombre}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="En Nombre" 
                                               Margin="4,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolEnNombre}"
                                              Visibility="{Binding EnableEnNombre, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Visible}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>

                        <GridViewColumn Width="80">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding TousEnDates}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="En Dates"
                                               Margin="4,0" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </GridViewColumnHeader>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding BoolEnDates}"
                                              Visibility="{Binding EnableEnDates, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}, FallbackValue=Visibl}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="120"
                                        Header="Début">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DtDebut}" 
                                                FontSize="10"
                                                Height="16"
                                                BorderThickness="0"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="120"
                                        Header="Fin">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DtFin}"
                                                FontSize="10"
                                                Height="16"
                                                BorderThickness="0"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Colonnes">
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ColonnesTransfert}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StLibelle}"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

Does anyone know if indeed there can be a conflict between windows and a WPF screen?

Because I'm running out of ideas. Thanks for your feedback.

Soluce Edit :

```
      <EventSetter Event="ListViewItem.DragOver" Handler="ListViewItemDragOver"/>
      <EventSetter Event="ListViewItem.Drop" Handler="ListViewItemDrop"/>
      <EventSetter Event="ListViewItem.PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListViewItemPreviewMouseMove"/>
```

I have it, and I'm giving the information here in case it happens to someone else. 
The part with the "EventSetters" was a problem (it allowed dragging and dropping lines into the datagrid).
It works with all servers, but not the 2008 one. I don't know why, but by removing these three lines, everything works perfectly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF styling on Windows Server 2008 R2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25914351/wpf-styling-on-windows-server-2008-r2)

Comment: I tried, I get back the animations (highlighting for example), but the checkboxes still don't work anyway, only on these two servers in 2008 R-2

Comment: Try to localize the problem to a very short reproducable example, see [mcve].

Comment: Annnd i got it, thanks for this advice. I'll edit my original post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know if indeed there can be a conflict between windows and a WPF screen?

The differences depend on the *installed* version of the .NET Framework and the default control templates in Windows. The templates in Windows 8 and later make the controls look different than the templates on Windows 7 and earlier.

Besides all .NET Framework versions since .NET Framework 4.0 are in-place updates, meaning that you can only have one of these installed on a machine and that framework assemblies are replaced when you install a new version. This may lead to different behaviours in your applications even if you *target* the same version at build time.

Migrating to .NET Core solves the assembly conflicts.